# Detecting enter key on a svg element

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg

I am trying to make my web site more accessible by making navigable with keyboard input only. To do so I need to be able to tab to a dynamically created SVG element, g, and then press enter to open a modal with more information.

I can detect when any key is pressed but not specifically enter. I have seen lots of people describing how to detect an enter keypress on a input element, but that does not fix my issue. The problem I have run into is that myEvent is just a normal event and not a keyboard event. So it does not have a keycode. I have also seen it suggested to use myEvent.key or myEvent.which, which it also does not have. So I don't know how to get the information of what key was pressed.

I don't know it this info is helpful but my website is a family history tree viewing web app so each SVG element is the visual representation of a node in a tree. I am trying to tab across every node and display more information about the focused node's person when enter is pressed.

```
 var g:Element = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");

 g.setAttribute('tabindex', "0"); // So I can tab to the element

 g.addEventListener("keypress",  function (myEvent) {
      // To this point everything works.

      // The next line gives an error.
      if(myEvent.keyCode === 13) { // 13 is enter
           // Open my modal
      }
 });
```

Comment: What error does it return? Because I see nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: it returns void

Comment: 1) What browser are you using for testing? 2) Have you tried using `keydown`  or `keyup` instead? (`keypress` is depreciated - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) 3) Have you tried using `myEvent.key` instead? (`keycode` is depreciated - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)

Comment: yeah I have tried keydown with myEvent.key I still get the error "Property 'key' does not exist on type 'Event'.ts(2339)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do a cast.

```js
var container:Element = document.createElement("div");
var svg:Element = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");

 var g:Element = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");

 g.setAttribute('tabindex', "0"); // So I can tab to the element

 g.addEventListener("keypress",  function (myEvent:KeyboardEvent) {
      // To this point everything works.
      
     console.log(myEvent);
      // The next line gives an error.
      if(myEvent.keyCode === 13) { // 13 is enter
          alert('enter');
      }
 });

var circle:Element = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
circle.setAttribute("cx", "20");
circle.setAttribute("cy", "20");
circle.setAttribute("r", "15");

g.appendChild(circle);
svg.appendChild(g);
container.appendChild(svg);
document.body.appendChild(container);
```